# Android Disable button when checkbox is not checked

Tags: java, android-studio

I have two `CheckBox` buttons in activity 2 and one `RadioButton` in activity 1. I want the `RadioButton`enabled in activity 1 when both of the `CheckBox` checked in activity 2 ??

Comment: Please provide the code that you have now. Your question made me really confused.

Comment: Hi Saloni, please review this link for how to write a good question on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  For starters, we need to see some code to understand what you are looking for.